# Side Navbar with custom design

Tags: html, css

[Imagen de un diseno en UPlabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIzAW.png)

Hi im trying to make a navbar like this but i cant finish it.
someone can help me? Only want to know how round the border of links when they are active

Now i have this resolved, but i dont know how round borders on the container of the links like we see in the design of UpLabs
[Image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVO1o.png)

HTML

```
<div id="navbar" class="sticky-top">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-content-center" style="height: 20%;">
          <img class="{{url}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <nav class="nav flex-column ml-4">
          <a id="link" routerLink="sales" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3 p-0 text-right">
                <i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-9">
                Ventas
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a id="link" routerLink="debtors" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3 p-0 text-right">
                <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-9">
                Deudores
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a id="link" routerLink="balance" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3 p-0 text-right">
                <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-9">
                Balance
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a id="link" routerLink="products" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-3 p-0 text-right">
                <i class="fas fa-boxes"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-9">
                Productos
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </nav>
</div>
```

and this is the file CSS that round borders of links when they are active and other parts of desing.

```
div#navbar {
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 0 40px 40px 0;
  background: #f4755f;
}

a#link {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background: #fbf3f2;
  color: #f4755f !important;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find online, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: In addition to @PedroRodrigues: You could at least show us the code, you already have, and where exactly you're stuck now ;)

Comment: Sorry, now i uplouded the code that i actually have

Answer (score 0):

Making the border of a link round is done like that:

**html:**

```
<a href="">Link 1</a>
```

**css**

```
a {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0 10px;
}
```

To make it round only when it is active you need to add a class to the active link and style that instead of the a tag, though.